# Get current slide data of slick Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can I get the data of the current slide of the slick using Angularjs? I've been solving this one for hours and I only got to read about how they got it using jQuery, which is not what I needed because I'm using angularjs.

This is my code:

```
<div ng-if="data && ready">
    <slick infinite="true" slides-to-show="1" slides-to-scroll="1" current-index="" dots="true" arrows="true" init-onload="true" data="data">
    <div ng-repeat="xx in data" >
     <img src="@{{xx.banner}}" alt="grid-1"/>
      <p>@{{xx.referno}}</p>
    <p>@{{xx.name}}</p>
    <p>@{{xx.address}}</p>
    </div>
    </slick>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean `data of the current slide`?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect whenever i slide the slick slider i want to get the data of the current slide

Comment: I understand that but what data? html or everything that is visible in the display?

Comment: just the index of the current data in the slide

Comment: What slick you are using?

Comment: I used this one https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick

Comment: Search for `beforeChange` or `afterChange` event of the slick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want the `index` of the current slide you are almost there! As you have already done, use the `current-index` attribute. But make sure you initialize it beforehand by using `ng-init`.

Let's assume your current index is `myIndex`. I have edited your code as follows:

```
<div ng-if="data && ready" ng-init="myIndex = 0">
  <slick current-index="myIndex" infinite="true" slides-to-show="1" slides-to-scroll="1" dots="true" arrows="true" init-onload="true" data="data">
    <div ng-repeat="xx in data" >
     <img src="@{{xx.banner}}" alt="grid-1"/>
      <p>@{{xx.referno}}</p>
    <p>@{{xx.name}}</p>
    <p>@{{xx.address}}</p>
    </div>
    <p>Current index: {{ myIndex }}</p>
  </slick>
</div>
```

Let me know how it goes :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the **current slide** data using the `beforeChange` event of slick

```
// On before slide change
$('your_slick_element_id_or_class').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  console.log(currentSlide);
  $scope.$apply(); // use this if the changes not applied or remove if you get the error "digest method is already running"
});
```

Comment: At the very least there needs to be a `$scope.$apply();` for angular to pick up on the changes. Or rather: If this is actually the true answer to the question, then angular-slick is one lazy angular-directive!

Comment: I don't know exactly but as suggested in the respective slick he never used `$scope.$apply()`. May be the `digest` function is already in running

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who has the same problem with mine. I had a hard time using vasyabigi angular slick, then i found this one

> https://github.com/devmark/angular-slick-carousel

It solved my problem.

I hope it helps.